# Trouble displaying the content of DataGrid

Tags: visual-studio

> Hi can i ask someone on how to easily display the content of my database using dataGridView, I already managed to update the inputted datas into the database. can you also give me some tips on my project.
>
> I am using access as My database

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class stor
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StorBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database7DataSet)
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Complete all the Information")
        Else
            Try
                Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gui\Documents\Database7.accdb;")
                Dim insert As String = "Insert into stor values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "');"
                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("create success")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("error")
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub stor_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database7DataSet.stor' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StorTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database7DataSet.stor)

    End Sub

End Class
```

[Click Here to view my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auYcP.png)

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please add some code and try to describe exactly your problem with the datagrid. And: there is a lot of documentation around, so perhaps you'll have to do a little research on your own.

Comment: there's my code i don't know how am i going to display the data's in my database through DataGridView.